Start parallel task and wait for it later in Jenkins Pipeline
In Java I can start a parallel thread, let it run and catch up/join with it later.
I know how to start parallel task in Jenkins Pipeline but how can I let them run and do other stuff meanwhile and catch up with them later?
Callable<MyResult> callable = new Callable<MyResult>() { ... };
Future<MyTask> task = executor.execute(callable);

do other things here

MyResult res = task.get()

